# Timepicker textcolor issue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-timepicker

I have this weird error where I pop up dialog to ask user to enter date and time in tabview.
the datepicker works fine but the timepicker is showing white text on white background and its almost invisible.

Here's my code for tabview.

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) timerDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    final TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
    final FrameLayout tabContent = tabHost.getTabContentView();
    TextView[] originalTextViews = new TextView[tabWidget.getTabCount()];

    for (int index = 0; index < tabWidget.getTabCount(); index++) 
    {
        originalTextViews[index] = (TextView) tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(index);
    }
    tabWidget.removeAllViews();

    for (int index = 0; index < tabContent.getChildCount(); index++) 
    {
        tabContent.getChildAt(index).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < originalTextViews.length; index++) 
    {
        final TextView tabWidgetTextView = originalTextViews[index];
        final View tabContentView = tabContent.getChildAt(index);
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec((String) tabWidgetTextView.getTag());

        tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
        {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) 
                {
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        ((TimePicker)tabContentView).setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                        ((TimePicker)tabContentView).setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        return tabContentView;
                }

            });
        if (tabWidgetTextView.getBackground() == null) 
        {
            tabSpec.setIndicator(tabWidgetTextView.getText());
        } 
        else 
        {
            tabSpec.setIndicator(tabWidgetTextView.getText(), tabWidgetTextView.getBackground());
        }
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
    AlertDialog timer = timerAlert.create();
    timer.show();
    timer.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) 
        {
            if(isSaveClicked)
            {
                TimePicker startTime = (TimePicker) timerDialog.findViewById(R.id.startTimePicker);
                TimePicker endTime = (TimePicker) timerDialog.findViewById(R.id.endTimePicker);

                 int eHour   = endTime.getCurrentHour();
                 int eMinute = endTime.getCurrentMinute();

                 int sHour   = startTime.getCurrentHour();
                 int sMinute = startTime.getCurrentMinute();

                 Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                 Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();

                 startCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
                 startCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);

                 endCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, eHour);
                 endCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, eMinute);

                 Log.d("silencer","start"+startCal.getTimeInMillis()+" end "+endCal.getTimeInMillis());
                 if(startCal.getTimeInMillis()>endCal.getTimeInMillis()||startCal.getTimeInMillis()==endCal.getTimeInMillis())
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start time must be less then end time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                 else
                 ba.updateOrInsertSilence(startCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis(), MainActivity.this,1);
            }
       }
    });
```

And Xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
            android:tag="Start"
            android:text="Start Time"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="End"
            android:text="End Time"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
             <TimePicker 
                 android:id="@+id/startTimePicker"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 style="@android:style/Theme.Light"/>
             <TimePicker
                    android:id="@+id/endTimePicker"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     style="@android:style/Theme.Light"/>

       </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>



</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea about how to set the color to black?

Comment: Why did you use `style="@android:style/Theme.Light"` for the TimePickers?

Comment: I used theme.light cause it resembles my application theme. Should i remove it?